# CSS z-index issue in my calendar control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a css z-index issue. It is a calendar control show events popup on mouseover red area.

Please see the image attached.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ea75jvdf/

When I mouseover on date 5 it shows popup but red div of other dates comes in front.

CSS of red icon

```
.add-gun {
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 8px;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: red;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the     transform: rotateY(0deg); on your div.day that is causing it. If you remove that then it works as expected.

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/51L7eac4/1/

I just quickly hacked it to remove it

```
applyTransform: function($el, transform) {
        //$el.css('transform', transform);
        //$el.css('-ms-transform', transform);
        //$el.css('-moz-transform', transform);
        //return $el.css('-webkit-transform', transform);
        return $el;
      },
```

Now I dont know if that serves some purpose in some cases where you don't wnat to remove it. Just the first thing I found from playing in Inspect Element.

Answer (score 2):

You should add z-index properties in this selector:

```
.responsive-calendar .days .day:hover {
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
    z-index: 10;
```